# Replacing All Column and Table Names in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have about 20 tables in my database where I use the word 'car' in many of the table names and the column names.

Is there a script or tool that will allow me to replace every instance of 'car' with 'vehicle'?  I do not want to replace any of the table data itself.

Comment: Export the databse to a SQL file, do a search/replace on the generated file (taking care to not replace values), recreate your database. This will be the fastest way.

Comment: @JorgeCampos This doesn't work since there are a huge amount of data within the tables that contain the word 'car'

Comment: You might have to be your own tool.  If you have foreign keys involved, you might have to create new tables, populate from the old ones, then drop the old ones.

Comment: Huge amount of data wouldn't be a problem if you have a tool to use regexes.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Great non-answer follow-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate the `RENAME TABLE` statements with a query, then simply copy and execute them.

```
select concat('rename table ', table_name, ' to ', substring_index(table_name, 'car', 1), 'vehicle',  substring_index(table_name, 'car', -1), ';')
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_schema'
  and table_name like '%car%';
```

The `substring-index` will return what is before the first occurence of 'car' when given 1.

It will return what is after when given -1.

Comment: Do you have a solution for the column names?

Comment: Do the same for `information_schema.columns` instead of `.tables`.